# Interesting theorems/facts about identification spaces

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, soft-question

I am now studying algebraic topology (still at the beginning). I am now studying identification spaces, adjunction spaces,... As I still don't know how these concepts are going to be used, I think I am getting a bit less interested. I would like you to present to me interesting theorems  about identification maps or theorems (not necessarily about identification maps) which are easier to understand, prove using the concept of identification maps. I think good examples of these would keep me motivated.

I am not looking for basic facts such as the composition of two identification maps is an identification map or other easy facts.

I realize that this question might be ambiguous, thus I don't mind deleting it if I don't get a response

Comment: Well, I would suggest instead that you take this opportinity to train yourself in sustaining your interest. In your mathematical education you are going to be introduced to many subjects whose interest will not be immediately apparent to you, and by all means you have to develop a habit of *not getting less interested*. Rest assured that the construction of identification spaces is extraordinarily useful, and hold your breath.

Comment: @MarianoSuarez-Alvarez Thanks for the advice. I am going to study it anyways. I just wanted to boost my motivation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A common source of (particularly nice) identification spaces comes from group actions on topological spaces.

Given any set $X$ and a group $G$, a group action of $G$ on $X$ is a function from $G\times X\rightarrow X$, denoted by $(g,x) \mapsto g\cdot x$ which is required to satisfy two axioms:

1. $e\cdot x = x$ where $e\in G$ is the identity element and $x\in X$ is anything.
2. $(gh)\cdot x = g\cdot(h\cdot x)$

In the case where $X$ is a topological space, we further require that for every $g\in G$, the function $\phi_g:X\rightarrow X$ given by $\phi_g(x) = g\cdot x$ be a homeomorphism.

Now, we can define an equivalence relation on $X$ by the following:  $$x\sim y \iff g\cdot x = y \text{ for some } g\in G.$$

Bullet point 1 tells us that $\sim$ is reflexive.  Using $g^{-1}$ shows that $\sim$ is symmetric, and bullet point 2 tells us that $\sim$ is transitive.  All that together just means that $\sim$ really is an equivalence relation.

One can then consider the identification set $X/\sim$.  It turns out, if $X$ is a topological space, the condition that all of the $\phi_g$ functions are homeomorphism is exactly what we need in order to put a topology on $X/\sim$ in such a way that the natural projection $\pi:X\rightarrow X/\sim$ is continuous.

What are some examples of this?  For starters, every example (except for the sphere) in Thomas Andrews's first paragraph is of this form for an action of $G = \mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}^2$ on $X=\mathbb{R}^2$.  His second paragraph is also of this form for $G = \mathbb{Z}$ and $X=\mathbb{R}$.

But there are many more examples.  If you've seen covering spaces, the fundamental group of a space acts on its universal covering, giving back the space as the quotient.  An example of this:  $G=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ acts on the sphere $S^n$ and the quotient is $\mathbb{R}P^n$.  Relatedly, $G = S^1$ (thought of as the group of unit complex numbers) acts on $S^{2n+1}$ with quotient $\mathbb{C}P^n$.

Answer (score 7):

A lot of the "fun" spaces are just idenfitication spaces on very simple spaces like squares and cubes. For example, the Klein bottle, the Möbius strip, the sphere, and the torus are all viewable as identification spaces on a simple square with interior.

The circle can be seen as the identification space of the real line with $x\sim y$ if and only if $x-y$ is an integer.

Identification spaces are how we build stuff up out of smaller spaces - whenever we "glue" two spaces together, what we are really doing is creating an identification space on the disjoint union of the spaces.

Comment: Thank you, I am aware that gluing is an identification. I don't quite see why the circle can be seen as the identification space of the real line with x∼y if and only if x−y is an integer.

Comment: Let $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}/∼$ send each element to its equivalence class and equip $\mathbb{R}/∼$ with the final topology with respect to $\mathbb{R}$.I think if we remove the equivalence class $\mathbb{Z}$ from $\mathbb{R}/∼$ the space becomes disconnected, however one can not remove any point from the unit circle to disconnect it.

Comment: .It looks like I did not ask a good question. +1 thank you again

Comment: And it wasn't a bad question - if your class or book really defines identification spaces without giving interesting examples, that is a deficiency of the class/book, and your question is valid.

Comment: Identification spaces in general can be really badly behaved. For example, if you defined $x\sim y$ as $x-y$ is rational on $\mathbb R$ then the space you get is just horrible. Such spaces you generally don't need. So as a general concept, it can be "too much." You generally like your equivalence relationship to be "nice" in some way to make the new space "nice."

Comment: Sorry, I posted something wrong above. The image of a disconnected space can be connected. The image of a *connected* space cannot be disconnected.

Comment: I am self-studying. My book gives examples, I just felt it wasn't enough.

Comment: I still don't see how the circle can be seen as the identification space of the real line with x∼y if and only if x−y is an integer

Comment: Consider the map: $f:\mathbb R\to S^1$ defined as $f(x)=(\cos 2\pi x,\sin 2\pi x)$. This sends $x$ and $y$ to the same point on the circle if and only if $x-y$ is an integer. This turns out to be exactly the identification. @Amr

Comment: Ah OK I see the mistake I made

Answer (score 4):

$B^n/S^{n-1}\cong S^n$ is pretty interesting to me.

Comment: +1 I know this one. This one is interesting for me. I would be glad to see others